# extract text between 2 different matches

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I am trying to extract text between specific first match(_ and -). for example, I need to get number 5 from below:

```
MQSeriesRuntime_5-U200491-7.5.0-4.x86_64
```

I tried awk field seperator (awk -F) but thats getting me the entire text after _.

Answer (score 8):

You just need to be creative about your field separator:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS="_|-"} {print $2}' input
5
```

The trick with `FS` is that it's not a string; it's a regular expression.

To explain a little more fully as you request below:

An `awk` script may define a code block named `BEGIN` which executes before any of the incoming data are processed.

I use this code block to define the field separator (`FS`) using a regular expression as either a hyphen (`-`) or underscore (`_`).

The next code block, `{print $2}`, will print the second field (i. e. the second string of characters as delimited by the heretofore separator, `/-|_/`), which is the `5` which you seek.  A code block with no prefix will execute for every record which is read by `awk`.

Comment: That worked, thanks much!

can you please explain the BEGIN and { }part please

Comment: Or just use the `-F` flag, which is shorter: `awk -F '_|-' '{print $2}' input.txt`

Comment: I keep forgetting `-F` is a thing, because my `awk`ings have been complex enough to generally need `BEGIN` blocks anyhow (:

Comment: Given the "first matches" requirements this is a really neat solution.

Answer (score 4):

By using the `-F` parameter, can achieve a slightly shorter solution.

```
$ awk -F'-|_' '{print $2}' input
5
```

Answer (score 1):

***sed*** alternative approach:

```
sed 's/^[^_-]*_\([^_-]*\)-.*/\1/' file
5
```

Comment: You fit two smileys into the regex.  Nice.  `[^_-]`

Comment: @Wildcard, that's funny `[^_-]`

Answer (score 1):

#### Python

With use of `<<<` to redirect the desired string into the `stdin` of python interpreter and with `re.split()` we can take out the second item in the resulting list of items being split at the two separators.

```
$ python -c 'import re,sys; print(re.split("-|_",sys.stdin.readline())[1])'  <<< "MQSeriesRuntime_5-U200491-7.5.0-4.x86_64"                          
5
```

Alternatively, we could just give the string as command-line argument and operate on `sys.argv[1]`:

```
$ python3 -c 'import re,sys; print(re.split("-|_",sys.argv[1])[1])' "MQSeriesRuntime_5-U200491-7.5.0-4.x86_64"                                       
5
```

This works with Python 2 and 3.  If we want to process a file and extract input from each line in this manner, we can do the following:

```
$ cat input.txt
MQSeriesRuntime_5-U200491-7.5.0-4.x86_64
MQSeriesRuntime_2-U200491-7.5.0-4.x86_64
MQSeriesRuntime_6-U200491-7.5.0-4.x86_64
$ python3 -c 'import re,sys; print("\n".join(map(lambda x: re.split("-|_",x)[1], sys.stdin.readlines())))'  < input.txt                              
5
2
6
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/2957781/53897:

```
echo MQSeriesRuntime_5-U200491-7.5.0-4.x86_64 | perl -n -e '/_([^-]+)/ && print $1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Could use `cut` with first delimiter `_` get the second collumn and then `cut` it again with `-` delimiter to get the first collumn.

```
echo MQSeriesRuntime_5-U200491-7.5.0-4.x86_64 | cut -d"_" -f2 | cut -d"-" -f1
```