# AWK: how to extract pattern between 2 custom field separators regardless of pattern's position on the line?

Tags: linux, awk, pattern-matching

Here is a fragment of a line in file:

```
LN=FINE FOODS & PHARMACEUTICALS NTM, MIC=XAIM, RIC=FF.MI, SG=MA1
```

I am interested in extracting the value of tag "MIC", i.e. my desired output is:

```
XAIM
```

The whole line is quite long:

```
20200403: #379 IT0005215329 {CU=EUR, GTPID=144115188076657542, II=IT0005215329, IS=18814564, LN=FINE FOODS & PHARMACEUTICALS NTM, MIC=XAIM, RIC=FF.MI, SG=MA1, SN=801670, STY=ORDINARY, TK="0.0002 to 0.1,0.0005 to 0.2,0.001 to 0.5,0.002 to 1,0.005 to 2,0.01 to 5,0.02 to 10,0.05 to 20,0.1 to 50,0.2 to 100,0.5 to 200,1 to 500,2 to 1000,5 to 2000,10 to 5000,20 to 10000,50 to 20000,100 to 50000,200", TS=FF, TY=S, UQ=1}
```

The position on the line of the tag "MIC" is not always the same.

I read through quite a few tutorials and it seems that all of their solutions involves creating a custom field separators and then extracting a desired pattern by using pattern's position on the line.

For example, I attempted to follow along the example given in [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/377770/extract-text-between-2-different-matches), namely I used this code to extract value from "MIC" tag:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="MIC=|,"} {print $2}' input.txt
```

I got the following output:

```
GTPID=144115188076657542
```

If you check the whole line sample that I provided above, the output is the value of the second tag "GTPID" that has "=" symbol. At first I was thinking that `{FS="MIC=|,"}` meant "create two custom field separators, the 1st one being `MIC=` and the 2nd one being `,` and for some reason I expected that `{print $2}` will print out whatever is between those two field separators.

But obviously the code above prints the value of whatever pattern that contains symbol "=" happens to be 2nd on the line.

How do I extract value that is between `MIC=` and `,` then?

Comment: The right answer would depend on whether your input is more complicated than you, and whether your script is more complicated than you show. For what you have there, `sed -n 's/.*MIC=\([^,]*\).*/\1/p'` would do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you have name=value pairs in your data it's best to first create an array that captures that mapping (`f[]` below) and then you can just access whatever fields you like by their name(s), e.g.:

```
$ awk -F'[=,] *' '{for (i=1;i<NF;i+=2) f[$i]=$(i+1); print f["MIC"]}' file
XAIM
```

Look at how easy that is to adapt to test values, print other fields in any order, etc.:

```
awk -F'[=,] *' '
    { for (i=1;i<NF;i+=2) f[$i]=$(i+1) }
    (f["MIC"] == "XAIM") && (f["LN"] ~ /FOOD/){ print f["SG"], f["RIC"] }
' file
MA1 FF.MI
```

Comment: Except that won't print anything at all for `f["CU"]` and will print bogus values for `f["UQ"]` or `f["TK"]` in the OP's example. It also won't "adapt" at all if the `TK="..."` happens to contain an odd number of commas -- your example generates bogus array entries like `f["0.0005 to 0.2"]="0.001 to 0.5"`. While awk is powerful enough to parse such recursive/structured data, pseudo-solutions like this give it a bad rap.

Comment: It's a solution for the problem the OP has, not an all inclusive solution for every possible variation of the problem that the OP doesn't have. Why not start ranting about it not handling newlines or escaped quotes inside quoted strings while you're at it? Why not assume there might be some variation that uses {} or some other structure to create hierarchies of fields and then complain it doesn't handle that either?

Comment: Behave, don't call people "ranting" for pointing out how broken and ridiculous your stuff is. Yes, why not handling escape quotes inside quoted strings? Your solution is no better than `awk '{print"XAIM"}'`.

Comment: `awk '{print"XAIM"}'` would output `XAIM` even if `MIC` wasn't present in the input or was assigned a different value like `MIC=RANT`. There are all sorts of improvements we COULD make for efficiency, robustness, etc. but obviously since they accepted it the script I posted is adequate for the OPs needs so, as is frequently the case, there's no need to go writing a lengthier script that solves problems the OP simply doesn't have.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sed -n 's/.* MIC=\([^,}]*\).*/\1/p' file
XAIM
```

This uses `sed` to match the  `MIC=SOMETHING,` or `MIC=SOMETHING}` string, and replaces the whole line with the `SOMETHING` string.  All other data is discarded.

---

```
$ tr ',' '\n' <file | awk -F '=' '$1 == " MIC" { print $2 }'
XAIM
```

This first replaces all commas by newlines and then runs `awk` with  a `=` character as field delimiter.  When the first field is equal to  `MIC`, the second field is printed.

---

```
$ awk -F ',' '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) if (sub(" MIC=","",$i)) print $i }' file
XAIM
```

This only uses `awk` and treats the input as comma separated fields.  It iterates over all fields, and when a field starts with the string  `MIC=`, that string is removed from the field and the remainder is printed.

---

If the file had been in JSON format (I'm thinking you may have transformed the data *from* JSON at some point as most REST APIs return JSON formatted DATA, and this data seems to be related to financial stock markets):

```json
{
  "CU": "EUR",
  "GTPID": 144115188076657540,
  "II": "IT0005215329",
  "IS": 18814564,
  "LN": "FINE FOODS & PHARMACEUTICALS NTM",
  "MIC": "XAIM",
  "RIC": "FF.MI",
  "SG": "MA1",
  "SN": 801670,
  "STY": "ORDINARY",
  "TK": "0.0002 to 0.1,0.0005 to 0.2,0.001 to 0.5,0.002 to 1,0.005 to 2,0.01 to 5,0.02 to 10,0.05 to 20,0.1 to 50,0.2 to 100,0.5 to 200,1 to 500,2 to 1000,5 to 2000,10 to 5000,20 to 10000,50 to 20000,100 to 50000,200",
  "TS": "FF",
  "TY": "S",
  "UQ": 1
}
```

then `jq` would have been easiest:

```
$ jq -r '.MIC' file1
XAIM
```

Answer (score 1):

With `grep` and `cut`.  Use `grep -o` to take `o`nly the matched data, look for the requested field and value.  Feed that to `cut`, using `=` as a field seperator, and take the second field:

```
$ grep -o 'MIC=[^,]*' input | cut -d= -f2
XAIM
```

With `sed`.  Look for the requested field/value pair, use `()` and `\1` to extract the matching subpattern:

```
$ sed -nE 's/^.*MIC=([^,]+).*$/\1/;p' input
XAIM
# or, alternatively,
$ sed -n 's/^.*MIC=\([^,]*\).*$/\1/;p' input
XAIM
```

With `awk`.  Set the field separator and record separator to `=` and `,` respectively.  For the record with the matching pattern, print the second field (i. e. the value):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { FS="="; RS=","; } $1 ~ /MIC/ { print $2 }' input
XAIM
```

Comment: `grep -Po '\bMIC=\K[^,]*'`

Comment: I usually take careful heed of warnings in manual pages, in relevant case that `--perl-regexp` is "highly experimental".

Comment: Nope. pcre is running the world, literally (GNU grep is using pcre for `-P`). grep's `-E` engine is much buggier. Your answer is assuming GNU grep, anyways.

Comment: And yet the admonition in the manual page persists.

Comment: You should ignore it.

Comment: Interesting suggestion.  Usually the advice is to RTFM, not to ITFM.

Comment: strange thing happens when I use your awk solution - if on the input file line there is a "{" symbol right before "MIC=", the value will not be extracted.
For example, if line contains {MIC=XAIM, CU=EUR, GTPID=1}, pattern "XAIM" cannot be extracted, but if line contains  {CU=EUR, MIC=XAIM, GTPID=1} everything works OK

Comment: @kamokoba you make an effort and adjust the script a bit: change the `RS=","` to `RS=" *[{},] *"`. Anyways, awk is not meant for parsing such structured data, that will break as soon as the text inside the `TK="..."` contains any characters like `,` or `=`.

Comment: You should mention that `RS=" *[{},] *"` would require GNU awk.

Comment: @EdMorton No, I would not say exactly that. The awk implementation which I prefer and is the default on many systems (mawk) has supported regular expression RS since at least 20 years. And, according to Arnold D. Robbins (the GNU awk author and maintainer) that feature is [now also supported in bwk](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/commit/?id=9c626e168999cb6072a31e90)

Comment: Fine, then say that. Or say it's non-POSIX. Or SOMETHING to give someone reading this in future a heads up that it will only work in a specific subset of awks.

Comment: @UncleBilly thanks for the tips. Could you advise what tool would be the most suitable to parse such structured data as provided in my example? This data comes from a Java utility which converts bit stream to formatted text, but this utility lacks built-in options to extract the MIC value, for example. So we always have to resort to grep/sed/awk

Comment: @kamokoba perl's regexes are able to parse such recursive data formats. However, they're not for the faint of heart ;-) I'll give you a example when I get a device with an actual keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

command

```
 awk -F "," '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /MIC/){gsub(/.*=/,"",$i);print $i}}}'
```

filename

output

```
XAIM
```